# makefile is missing separator

Tags: makefile, syntax-error, gnu-make

Alright I am stuck on this and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Everything was going great working on a more complicated makefile but then all of a sudden I got the "Missing separator" error. I was able to isolate it down to a very simple scenario:

### test.mk

```
define push_dir
$(info ${1})
endef

define pop_dir
$(info ${1})
endef

define include_submake
$(call push_dir,${1})
$(call pop_dir,${1})
endef
```

### Simple

```
include test.mk

INITIAL_SUBMAKE:= includeme.mk
$(call include_submake,${INITIAL_SUBMAKE})

process:
    @echo Processed...
```

And the output:

```
C:\project>make -f Simple process
includeme.mk
includeme.mk
Simple:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

`includeme.mk` does not actually exist. I have no idea what is going wrong here I have tried a multitude of things. If I surround the call to include_submake in info like so:

```
$(info $(call include_submake,${INITIAL_SUBMAKE}))
```

The missing separator error goes away. Also If in the `include_submake` define I only call one of the functions it works fine. Additionally if I directly call the functions instead of calling them `include_submake` it works as well:

```
include test.mk

INITIAL_SUBMAKE:= includeme.mk
$(call push_dir,${INITIAL_SUBMAKE})
$(call pop_dir,${INITIAL_SUBMAKE})

process:
    @echo Processed...


C:\project>make -f Simple process
includeme.mk
includeme.mk
Processed...
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something fundamental here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also not sure what happened with the copy paste but for the process: target I do have a tab in front of the @echo command

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `missing separator` error happens because of a non-empty return value of `include_submake`, which is a single line feed character in your case. Make only permits whitespace characters (that is, a space or tab) to occur in an expression which is not assumed to be a part of some rule or another directive.

Rewrite your functions using plain-old Make variable assignment and the error should go away:

```
push_dir = \
    $(info $1)

pop_dir = \
    $(info $1)

include_submake = \
    $(call push_dir,$1) \
    $(call pop_dir,$1)
```

## UPD.: `define` vs plain old variable assignment

Answering to a question from the first comment. Personally I would prefer using `define` directive in several cases.

### Using with `eval` function

As the GNU Make manual suggests, `define` directive is very useful in conjunction with the [`eval` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function). Example from the manual (emphasis is mine):

```
PROGRAMS    = server client

server_OBJS = server.o server_priv.o server_access.o
server_LIBS = priv protocol

client_OBJS = client.o client_api.o client_mem.o
client_LIBS = protocol

# Everything after this is generic

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGRAMS)

define PROGRAM_template
  $(1): $$($(1)_OBJS) $$($(1)_LIBS:%=-l%)
  ALL_OBJS   += $$($(1)_OBJS)
endef

$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))

$(PROGRAMS):
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(ALL_OBJS) $(PROGRAMS)
```

### Generator templates

Verbatim variables fit perfectly for cases when you want to generate a file from GNU Make. For example, consider generating a header file based on some information from Makefile.

```
# Args:
#   1. Header identifier.
define header_template
/* This file is generated by GNU Make $(MAKE_VERSION). */

#ifndef $(inclusion_guard)
#define $(inclusion_guard)

$(foreach inc,$($1.includes),
#include <$(inc).h>)

/* Something else... */

#endif /* $(inclusion_guard) */

endef

# 1. Unique header identifier.
inclusion_guard = \
    __GEN_$1_H

# Shell escape.
sh_quote = \
    '$(subst ','"'"',$1)'

foo.includes := bar baz

HEADERS := foo.h

$(HEADERS) : %.h :
    @printf "%s" $(call sh_quote,$(call header_template,$(*F)))> $@
```

### Extended Make syntax

In our project we use our own build system called [Mybuild](http://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/Mybuild), and it is implemented entirely on top of GNU Make. As one of low-level hacks that we used to improve the poor syntax of the builtin language of Make, we have developed a [special script](https://github.com/embox/embox/blob/b7839502277bba1fcb01c91c136a088c06176c2c/mk/core/define.mk) which allows one to use extended syntax for function definitions. The script itself is written in Make too, so it is a sort of meta-programming in Make.

In particular, one can use such features as:

- Defining multiline functions without the need to use backslash
- Using comments inside functions (in plain-old Make comments can only occur outside variable assignment directives)
- Defining custom macros like `$(assert ...)` or `$(lambda ...)`
- Inlining simple functions like `$(eq s1,s2)` (string equality check)

This is an example of how a function can be written using the extended syntax. Note that it becomes a valid Make function and can be called as usual after a call to `$(def_all)`.

```
# Reverses the specified list.
#   1. The list
# Return:
#   The list with its elements in reverse order.
define reverse
    # Start from the empty list.
    $(fold ,$1,

        # Prepend each new element ($2) to
        # the result of previous computations.
        $(lambda $2 $1))
endef
$(def_all)
```

Using these new features we were able to implement some really cool things (well, at least for Make :-) ) including:

- Object-Oriented layer with dynamic object allocation, class inheritance, method invocations and so on
- LALR parser runtime engine for parsers generated by [GOLD Parser Builder](http://goldparser.org/)
- Modelling library with runtime support for models generated with [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/)

Feel free to use any part of [the code](https://github.com/embox/embox/tree/b7839502277bba1fcb01c91c136a088c06176c2c/mk/core) in your own projects!

Comment: That definitely made the error go away. Is there a good way to reason about when you should use define vs the = semantics when using $(call? Going with what you said I can wrap the $(call) with $(strip) and everything works ok too. If there's any you can expound on it would be greatly appreciated. Unfortunately I only have 1 upvote to give.

Comment: wow! thanks man. great explanation and of course above and beyond. Going to upvote some of your other stuff. I am also going to take a look at your embox build system. I saw the site on your profile but I didn't get a chance to comb through it yet.

Comment: @ThePosey, you're welcome, and, oh, thanks for upvotes! Actually Embox is an operating system kernel, and Mybuild is a build automation and configuration tool used in Embox.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. I inserted 'tab', deleted 'tab', reinserted to be sure. Same error message.

But, I did all of this inside of XCodem which to my surprise inserted white spaces, not '\t'. Once I used different editor these 'phantom' errors went away.

HTH...

Comment: Thanks! Somehow there were 4 spaces instead of tab before function $(call).